# Django : attribute not defined in the "models.py" file

Tags: django, model

My "models.py" file has the following code:

```
 from django.db import models

 # Create your models here.

class Questions(models.Model):
   question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class  Choice (models.Model):  
    choice_text =  models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerFeild(default = 0 )
    question =  models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

The error I am getting while running the code is:

```
  votes = models.IntegerFeild(default = 0 )
  AttributeError: module 'django.db.models' has no attribute 'IntegerFeild'
```

Comment: Please check your spelling --> IntegerFeild --> IntegerField

Comment: Please read this --> https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/fields/#integerfield

Answer (score 0):

There's a typo in your models.py ,You can fix it like :-

```
votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0 )
```